# HC05 does not connect

Tags: android, bluetooth, stm32, hc-05

I am doing STM32 programming for my summer internship. Currently I am attempting to use an HC05 bluetooth module to send serial data over to the stm32 board. However, my HC05 bluetooth module does not connect to any of my devices. I am using android devices as well. I can find the device over bluetooth and I can pair the device as well, however it never connects. Does anyone know how I may be able to solve this issue. The HC05 is receiving 3.3 volts as well.

Comment: consider adding what have you tried so far(code or something except adding theoru)

Comment: There needs to be something on the Android phone that knows how to communicate with the HC-05 module. Have you tried using an app such as [Serial Bluetooth Terminal](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=de.kai_morich.serial_bluetooth_terminal)?

Answer (score 1):

The problem turned out to be a hardware problem by the hardware engineers, not a problem with my code. The TX of the board was connected to the Tx of the HC05 and the RX of the Board was connected to the RX of the HC05. It should have been connected the other way around

Answer (score 1):

which app are you using for testing your Bluetooth module? I recommend you use this one: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.clarence.bluetoothserial, with which you can customize your frequently used commands as buttons. It’s very convenient.